# Logout with facebook not working in monotouch app

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.ios

Hi i am new to monotouch  , i implemented login with facebook option in my monotouch app , for that i used facebook autharization view controller all are working fine, but when logout with facebook is not working properly

Any one please help me

this is the link for the code **https://gist.github.com/2520032**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it, we need to clear facebook cookies in logout button, that's it. No need to clear authtoken and etc....just 4 lines of code solved my problem.

```
NSHttpCookieStorage storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;

foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in storage.Cookies) 
{
    if(cookie.Domain == ".facebook.com")
    {
        storage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```